# MsalUiRequiredException when idle for some time using SQL Server for caching the Token

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-sdks

Using ASP.NET Core 3.1 and I was able to retrieve assigned roles on Azure Active Directory using Graph API, but after some time being idle, it throws a following exception on this line

```
var user = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
```

> MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the
> AcquireTokenSilent call.

Here's the whole code:

```
public class GraphService : IGraphService
{
    private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public GraphService(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
       _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
       _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public async Task<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> GetAssignedGroups()
    {
        var assignedGroups = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        try
        {
            var user = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
            var resourceId = _configuration.GetValue<string>("GraphQL:AppResourceId");

            var appRoleAssignments = await _graphServiceClient.Users[user.Id].AppRoleAssignments
                .Request()
                .Filter("resourceId eq " + resourceId)
                .GetAsync();

            var groups = appRoleAssignments.Where(x => x.PrincipalType.Equals("Group"));
            if (groups.Any())
            {
                   // add groups to existingUsers
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e.Message);
        }
        return assignedGroups;
    }
}
```

I call the service using a view component on the **_Layout.cshtml**

```
[ViewComponent(Name = "Student")] 
public class StudentViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly IGraphService _graphService;
    public WarehouseViewComponent(IGraphService graphService)
    {
        _graphService = graphService ?? throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(graphService));
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        var studentGroups = await _graphService.GetAssignedGroups();
            return View("Student", studentGroups);
    }
}
```

Then on my **Index.cshtml.cs**:

```
[Authorize]
[AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "DownstreamApi:Scopes")]
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
  public void OnGet()
    {
    }
}
```

I cache the token using SQL Server I followed the code:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-2-TokenCache

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public IWebHostEnvironment Env { get; set; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        Env = env;
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ConfigureDbContext(services);
        ConfigureDataServices(services);
        ConfigureHostedServices(services);
        ConfigureAuthentication(services);
        ConfigureAuthorization(services);
        ConfigureLocalization(services);
        ConfigureValidators(services);
        ConfigureTokenCache(services);
        ConfigureHttpContext(services);

        var builder = services.AddRazorPages()
            .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(o => o.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) => factory.Create(typeof(SharedResource)))
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSession();
    }

    

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        if (Env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseRequestLocalization();

        app.UseSession();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapRazorPages());
    }

    private void ConfigureAuthentication(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        string[] initialScopes = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;

        services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
                    .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                    .AddDistributedTokenCaches();

        services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            // Use the groups claim for populating roles
            options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
        });

        //services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
        //{
        //    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        //        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        //        .Build();
        //    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        //});

    }

    private void ConfigureAuthorization(IServiceCollection services) => services.AddAuthorization(options =>
                 {
                     options.AddPolicy(Roles.Admins, authBuilder => authBuilder.RequireRole(Roles.Admins));
                     options.AddPolicy(Roles.Students, authBuilder => authBuilder.RequireRole(Roles.Students));
                 });

    private void ConfigureDbContext(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("StudentDbConnStr");
        var tokenCacheConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("TokenCacheDbConnStr");
        _ = services.AddDbContext<StudentDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
        _ = services.AddDbContext<TokenCacheDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(tokenCacheConnectionString));
    }

    private void ConfigureHostedServices(IServiceCollection services) => services.AddHostedService<LogicAppsEmailService>();


    private void ConfigureLocalization(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        _ = services.AddLocalization(o => o.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

        _ = services.AddRazorPages().AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(o => o.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) => factory.Create(typeof(SharedResource)));

        _ = services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            var supportedCultures = new[]
            {
                new CultureInfo("de-DE"),
                new CultureInfo("en-US")
            };

            options.DefaultRequestCulture = Env.IsDevelopment() ? new RequestCulture("en-US") : new RequestCulture("de-DE");

            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
            options.RequestCultureProviders = new[] { new CookieRequestCultureProvider() };
        });
    }

    private void ConfigureDataServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        _ = services.AddScoped<IConfigurationService, ConfigurationService>();
        _ = services.AddScoped<IGraphService, GraphService>();
    }

    private void ConfigureValidators(IServiceCollection services) => services.AddSingleton<IValidationAttributeAdapterProvider, CustomValidationAttributeAdapterProvider>();

    private void ConfigureHttpContext(IServiceCollection services) => services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

    private void ConfigureTokenCache(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache(options =>
        {
            options.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("TokenCacheDbConnStr");
            options.SchemaName = "dbo";
            options.TableName = "TokenCaches";

            // You don't want the SQL token cache to be purged before the access token has expired. Usually
            // access tokens expire after 1 hour (but this can be changed by token lifetime policies), whereas

            // the default sliding expiration for the distributed SQL database is 20 mins. 
            // Use a value which is above 60 mins (or the lifetime of a token in case of longer lived tokens)
            options.DefaultSlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(90);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting the error only during debugging or in production?

Comment: haven't tried it production yet

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to clear the login cookie? Looks like the cookie is persisted but not the server-side session which leads to the exception during debugging.

When you clear the login cookie then login flow should be initiated again.

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandlerOptions
    {
        ExceptionHandler = async ctx =>
        {
            var handlerFeature = ctx.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
            if (handlerFeature != null)
            {
                if (handlerFeature.Error is MsalUiRequiredException
                    || handlerFeature.Error.InnerException is MsalUiRequiredException
                    || (handlerFeature.Error.InnerException != null && handlerFeature.Error.InnerException.InnerException is MsalUiRequiredException))
                {
                    ctx.Response.Cookies.Delete($"{CookieAuthenticationDefaults.CookiePrefix}{CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme}");
                    ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.Request.GetEncodedPathAndQuery());
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```